# Bootstrap navbar toggle is not working with Laravel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I've following code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>
            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "topMenu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#" class = 'navAnchor'>Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class = 'navAnchor'>Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class = 'navAnchor'>Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class = 'navAnchor'>Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also have tried to change

```
<div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" id = "topMenu">
```

but when I resize the screen to view on smaller screen, 3 bars appear, but clicking on them just do nothing.

**EDIT**
at the top of page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
```

and at the bottom, inside `body`

```
<link rel="text/javascript" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.js') }}" />
<link rel="text/javascript" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}" />
```

and by viewing the console(inspect element, it shows no error), every thing is being loaded properly.
can someone guide me to right way.

Thanks

Comment: Have you imported bootstrap css and js files?

Comment: Yes, as I've updated my question as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the problem is is that you are using the `link` tag where you actually should be using the `script` tag:

```
<link rel="text/javascript" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.js') }}" />
<link rel="text/javascript" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}" />
```

Javascript should be in a script tag for it to load into your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: That's why I love `StackoverFlow` :)

Thank you for pointing to exact location

Answer (score 1):

You have placed the javascript inside the **link** tag instead of **script** tag.**Link** is used for css and for **js** we use **script**.
write it inside the script tag as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{your_source_for_script}}"></script>
```